# How can I assert if a function does or does not call its parent?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, mockk

I'm trying to write a unit test for a RecyclerView adapter.  The twist is that I'm using DiffUtil and returning payload diffs, which calls `onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int, payloads: List<Any>` instead of (well, in addition to) the normal `onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int)`.  Based on [this tutorial](https://blog.undabot.com/recyclerview-time-to-animate-with-payloads-and-diffutil-4278beb8d4dd) the main part is:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TravelinoNormalItemViewHolder, position: Int, payloads: MutableList<Any>) {
    if (payloads.isEmpty())
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads)
    else {
        if (payloads.any { it is InfoMessageChanged })
            holder.view.alarmMessage.text = this.items[position].infoMessage
    }
}
```

So I want to write a test for this function and can't figure out how to verify or assert what happens.  I've created a minimal reproducible project that demonstrates my issues.  I can't figure out how to get both tests to pass.

```
import io.mockk.MockKVerificationScope
import io.mockk.spyk
import io.mockk.verify
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test

class TestyTest {

    private lateinit var child: ChildClass
    private lateinit var  verifyBlock: MockKVerificationScope.() -> Unit

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        // I've obviously tried many variations of mocks, spys, verifications, etc.
        val actual = ChildClass()
        child = spyk(actual)
        verifyBlock = {
            (child as ParentClass).doSomething("hi", any())
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun callParent() {
        child.doSomething("hi", true)
        verify(verifyBlock = verifyBlock)
    }

    @Test
    fun doNotCallParent() {
        child.doSomething("hi", false)
        verify(verifyBlock = verifyBlock, exactly = 0)
    }
}

// ParentClass is not mine to change.  Really is RecyclerView.Adapter
abstract class ParentClass {

    //public abstract void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VH holder, int position);
    abstract fun doSomething(any: Any)

    //public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VH holder, int position, @NonNull List<Object> payloads)
    open fun doSomething(any: Any, callParent: Boolean) {
        println("ParentClass.doSomething(Any,Boolean)")
        doSomething(any)
    }
}

// My adapter
class ChildClass : ParentClass() {

    //public abstract void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VH holder, int position);
    override fun doSomething(any: Any) {
        println("ChildClass.doSomething(Any)")
        println(any)
    }

    //public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VH holder, int position, @NonNull List<Object> payloads)
    override fun doSomething(any: Any, callParent: Boolean) {
        println("ChildClass.doSomething(Any,Boolean)")
        if(callParent) super.doSomething(any, callParent)
        else doSomething(any)
    }
}
```

The `verifyBlock` is extracted out to ensure both tests do the same thing.  I want to verify that when `callParent=true` that it calls the parent and when `callParent=false` that it doesn't.  Simple, right? But I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution.  I added a shim to the child class that does nothing valuable, but creates a seam to verify.

```
class ChildClass : ParentClass() {

    override fun doSomething(any: Any) {
        println("ChildClass.doSomething(Any)")
        println(any)
    }

    // added this
    fun doSomethingElse(any: Any) {
        doSomething(any)
    }

    override fun doSomething(any: Any, callParent: Boolean) {
        println("ChildClass.doSomething(Any,Boolean)")
        if(callParent) super.doSomething(any, callParent)
        else doSomethingElse(any)
    }
}
```

And the test is simply verifying if the new function is called:

```
class TestyTest {

    private lateinit var child: ChildClass
    private val verifyBlock: MockKVerificationScope.() -> Unit = { child.doSomethingElse(any<String>()) }

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        val actual = ChildClass()
        child = spyk(actual)
    }

    @Test
    fun callParent() {
        child.doSomething("hi", true)
        verify(exactly = 0, verifyBlock = verifyBlock)
    }

    @Test
    fun doNotCallParent() {
        child.doSomething("hi", false)
        verify(exactly = 1, verifyBlock = verifyBlock)
    }
}
```

I don't love adding a new function that does nothing (I can see someone - possibly me - trying to remove it in the future because it doesn't do anything) but it solved the problem for now.